# AJAX - pass the entire form + 1 or more data outside the form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I know how to pass the entire form to AJAX.

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

However, I don't know how to pass the form + values outside the form.

Ex:

```
var id = $('[name="formid"]').attr("id");
var uniq = $('[name="formid"]').data('uniquecode');

data: {form: $(this).serialize(), id: id, uniq: uniq},
```

This works, but the form turns into a query string instead of an array.

```
Array ( [form] => fullname=&contactnum=&email=&source= )
```

It should be like this:

```
Array ( [fullname] => [contactnum] => [email] => [source] => )
```

Someone help me doin' this? Thanks.

Comment: The `FormData` object is designed for this sort of purpose - can assign a form directly and append any items you want before sending via ajax

Comment: Indeed. It is useful when I have documents that needs to attach to my forms. But I didn't try to use it on passing multiple data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways using which you can get your solution.
Serialize returns you string so you can concatenate as

```
data: $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + id + "&uniq=" + uniq,
```

You can pass your values independetly of data in ajax as

```
    var id = $('[name="formid"]').attr("id");
var uniq = $('[name="formid"]').data('uniquecode');
    $.ajax({
       url:'',
       data : {
         data : data,
         id : id,
         uniq : uniq,
       },
    });
```

You can use hidden field as

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="your value" />
<input type="hidden" name="uniq" value="your other value" />
```

Also if you are passing as

```
data: {form: $(this).serialize(), id: id, uniq: uniq},
```

you can get the array at the backend in php using [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: I like the `parse_str` function. It worked to me. Although it adds at least 2 lines in my code but who cares? hahaha. Thanks. Helped me a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

As you can see - `serialize()` returns simple string, that's why you can concatenate it with your required values:

```
data: $(this).serialize() + "&id=" + id + "&uniq=" + uniq,
```

Another solution can be to create hidden inputs on the form with your required values:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="your value" />
<input type="hidden" name="uniq" value="your other value" />
```

Then they will be `serialize`d too, without doing anything else.

Comment: I also find this helpful. I can mark both answer as accepted. Hahaha. Anyways, I accept this answer.